# In iMovie, is there any way to apply a PIP dissolve at the end but not at the beginning?

Tags: imovie, macos

I am using picture-in-picture in an iMovie and it works great except that I can't seem to figure out if there is a way I can have a different transition into the PIP versus out of it at the end.

There seems to only be one selection where I can choice time and transition (like dissolve) and it applies that to **both** the beginning and end.

Is there any way to have a different transition in versus out of a picture in picture in iMovie?

Comment: What exact version of iMovie on which platform (OS X or iOS)?

Comment: latest version of both

Comment: Did my answer help? Need anything else?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. On iMovie 10.1.2 for macOS, all you need to do is hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key while dragging one of the picture-in-picture fade markers. Here's a video demo:

[image: iMovie PIP]

(**Note:** Press image for full size.)